# How to take only a single input from java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I know that `java.util.Scanner` has an automatic delimiter " ".  Is there any way I could get rid of someone entering more than one number in the same line of the console? I want it to become an invalid input. For example, I only desire single digits to be inputted at a time. I don't want someone to put in "2 5" or "23" on the same line. If they do, I don't want the computer to process each number.

Comment: use `nextLine` to read input and then use `matches("\\d")` to check for single digit input

Comment: `scanner.useDelimiter("\n")`

Comment: Show us what you tried and you can use `Scanner.findInLine(String pattern)` or `Scanner.findInLine(Pattern pattern)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your desired results, first check if the String is a number. To do this, use the `.matches("\\d")` function. This checks if the **Input** from the **Scanner** is a **single** **number**. Then, use the `Integer.parseInt(String);` function to take the string, and turn it into an integer. This way, you can use the userInput as an Integer instead of leaving it as a String.

**Here is the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    while (true){
    System.out.println("Type a single number in!\n");
    Scanner userInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInp = userInt.nextLine();
    if (userInp.matches("\\d")){// Checks if userInp is a single digit
      System.out.println("\nYou are correct!\n");
      int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userInp); // Turns the userInp(String) into the userNumber (Integer)
      System.out.println("Your number was " + userNumber + "!\n");// Prints out the number(which is now an Integer instead of a String)
    } else if (userInp.equals("-break")) {
      break;
    } else {
      System.out.println("\nYou are incorrect.\n");
      System.out.println("We couldn't read your number because it wasn't a single digit!\n");
    }
    }
    
  }   
}
```

**Here is the output:**

[image: Output]